# Android Studio how to change top bar title

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, titlebar

I have this navigation-drawer with fragments. I want that every time I go to a section of this, change the title above in the image it says "Usario"

Image of Navigation Drawer

[image: Image of Navigation Drawer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Usario");
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you change the fragment, set the title of your activity.

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
setTitle("something");
```